# My indicators in onboarding in Flutter are not affected by the animation

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    class _OnboardingState extends State<Onboarding> {
  final PageController pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  int currentPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            PageView(
              onPageChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  currentPage = value;
                });
              },
              controller: pageController,
              children: [
                 OnboardingWidget(
                  title: 'Title',
                  subtitle:'Subtitle',
                  image: 'assets/images/second-onboard.svg',
                ),
                 OnboardingWidget(
                  title: 'Title',
                  subtitle:'Subtitle',
                  image: 'assets/images/second-onboard.svg',
                ),
                OnboardingWidget(
                  title: 'Title',
                  subtitle:'Subtitle',
                  image: 'assets/images/second-onboard.svg',
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 4.h,
              child: CustomPageIndicator(
                currentPage: currentPage,
                totalPage: 3,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my onboarding page. Here, I call the OnboardingWidget I created and put it in the PageView and control the navigation.

```
    class CustomPageIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  final int currentPage;
  final int totalPage;

  const CustomPageIndicator(
      {super.key, required this.currentPage, required this.totalPage});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100.w,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 33.3.w,
            child: Text('Start',),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 33.3.w,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: List.generate(totalPage, (index) {
                return AnimatedPageIndicator(
                  isActive: index == currentPage,
                );
              }),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 33.3.w,
            child: Text('Next', ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here I added 2 texts and my indicators.

```
    class AnimatedPageIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isActive;

  const AnimatedPageIndicator({super.key, required this.isActive});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isActive) {
      return AnimatedContainer(
        curve: Curves.easeInOutQuart, // Animasyon eğrisini değiştirdik
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2000), //
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0),
        width: 18.0,
        height: 6.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: orange,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0),
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 3.0,
          backgroundColor: softblack2,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Here, I added an animation to the indicators and defined another shape for the active page and another shape for the inactive page.

My problem here is that no matter what I do or how many seconds I do the animation, I can't see this animation.